# math.asin() function returns incorrect value

Tags: python

The `math.sin()` function returns the correct value, but the `math.asin()` value is incorrect.

Code:

```
sineValue = math.sin(math.radians(125))
print(sineValue)
```

Expected output: `0.8191520442889917`

Actual output: `0.8191520442889917`

Code:

```
asineValue = math.asin(math.radians(0.75))
print(asineValue)
```

Expected output: `48.59037789`

Actual output: `0.01309034324060011`

As you can see the `asin` value is way off, even though it is run with the radian of `0.75`.

My expected output results were found with a handheld calculator. Not sure why the results would be different though.

Comment: The argument to `asin` is not an angle. You can't put it in radians.

Comment: @khelwood if I remove math.radians I still get an incorrect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `asin` is not an angle. You can't put it in radians.

The *return value* of `asin` is an angle in radians that you can convert to degrees if you want.

```
angle = math.degrees(math.asin(0.75))
```

Result:

```
48.590377890729144
```

Comment: Thanks. Assumed that the asin function worked the same as the sin function

Comment: No, the `sin` function computes the [sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) of an angle. The `asin` function is the opposite: it converts the sine to an angle. The angle is the thing that can be measured in degrees or radians. The sine itself is just a number.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're computing the arcsin of 125 degrees.  If so, you have to account for the range of arcsine (-90 degrees to +90 degrees):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values